# Way to extend y scale to required number in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to create bar chart from database data with query:

```
$myquery = "select column_nm, column_vl 
    from
    (
      select 'Head of Department' column_nm, COUNT(`team_role`) column_vl 
      from team WHERE team_role = 'HOD'
      union all
      select 'Supervisor', COUNT(team_role)
      from team WHERE team_role='Supervisor'
      union all
      select 'Checker', COUNT(team_role)
      from team WHERE team_role='Checker'   
      union all
      select 'Squad Leader', COUNT(team_role)
      from team WHERE team_role='Squad Leader'      
      union all
      select 'Team Member', COUNT(team_role)
      from team WHERE team_role='Team Member'
    ) d";
```

Here is what I get from this query:

```
| column_nm          | value_nm |
| Head of Department | 3        |
| Supervisor         | 9        |
| Checker            | 34       |
| Squad Leader       | 26       |
| Team Member        | 24       |
```

But when it comes to bar chart the maximum number of y scale is 9. Here is what i get in bar chart: [image]

If I remove supervisor column then it works fine and system displays correct number. What is the problem and how can I solve it?
And code for bar chart:

```
<script>
var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format("100");
//var formatPercent = 4
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function(d) {
return "<strong>"+ d.column_nm +":</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.column_vl + "</span>";
})

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.json("scoreboard_data.php", function(error, data) {
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.column_nm; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.column_vl; })]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Score");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.column_nm); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.column_vl); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.column_vl); })
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

});

function type(d) {
d.column_vl = +d.column_vl;
return d;
}

</script>
```

How can I change y scale to show the largest number out of all values? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain...

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.column_vl;
})]);
```

... was correctly set.

Therefore, this leaves us with only one explanation: you have **strings** in your data, not numbers.

This is easy to show if we treat your numbers as strings. You can see that the "maximum" will be `"9"` (as a string, not a number):

```js
var data = ["3", "9", "34", "26", "24"];
console.log("The maximum among those 'numbers' is: " + d3.max(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Also, if we remove the `supervisor` (which is "9"), the new maximum will be "34", which matches the behaviour you described.

**Solution:**

Convert your strings to numbers, either using a loop in your data or the unary operator in the domain:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return +d.column_vl;
    //     ^----- unary operator here 
})]);
```

Comment: Thanks for great explanation.